# xcopy invalid parameters - copying all files in folder

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, robocopy, xcopy

```
for /R "c:\" %f in ("*.pdf") do xcopy %f "%USERPROFILE%\all\text" /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
```

This is the command I am using to copy all of the .pdf files on my computer into one folder. However, it does not copy the files from folders with spaces in them. I did my research already. I tried setting the  `"c:\"` to `"c:\*.*"`, yet it still does not work.

How can I copy all .pdf files without changing the names of the folder?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you need to also put the double quotes around the `%f` variable placeholder after the `xcopy` command within the `FOR /R` loop so try the below and if it works, then that is your problem.

**Command Line Version**

```
for /R c:\ %f in ("*.pdf") do xcopy "%~f" "%USERPROFILE%\all\text" /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
```

**Batch Script Version**

```
for /R c:\ %%f in ("*.pdf") do xcopy "%%~f" "%USERPROFILE%\all\text" /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
```

Comment: The `~` in `%~f` is not required.